# how to show a category only if it is not empty

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, custom-post-type

i am using the following legacy code to pull post type GENRE and display the records on a wordpress site template file.

```
<?php
$genre_ids = get_posts('fields=ids&posts_per_page=-1&post_status=publish&post_type=genre&order=asc&orderby=title');
$choices = array(array('text' => 'Select Genre From List', 'value' => 0 ));
foreach ( $genre_ids as $genre_id ) {
    $categories[] = get_the_title( $genre_id );
}
if (!empty($categories)){
    foreach ($categories as $i=>$cat) {
        print "<li>";
        print "<a href='" . get_site_url() . "/band-search-page/?cat=$cat'>" . $cat . "</a>";
        print "</li>";
    }                       
} else {
    print "<li>";
    print "no categories";
    print "</li>";
}
```

the script works now to say if there is any post type GENRE then run the query. but i want to edit it to check and show the GENRE only if there is a GENRE. right now the query is showing all categories even if there is no data. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have to remove empty array elements using array_filter($cat);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code::

```
<?php

$genre_ids = get_posts('fields=ids&posts_per_page=-1&post_status=publish&post_type=genre&order=asc&orderby=title');
$choices = array(array('text' => 'Select Genre From List', 'value' => 0));
foreach ($genre_ids as $genre_id)
{
    $categories[] = get_the_title($genre_id);
}
if (!empty($categories))
{
    foreach ($categories as $i => $cat)
    {
        if (!empty($cat))
        {
            print "<li>";
            print "<a href='" . get_site_url() . "/band-search-page/?cat=$cat'>" . $cat . "</a>";
            print "</li>";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    print "<li>";
    print "no categories";
    print "</li>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line:

```
 print "<a href='" . get_site_url() . "/band-search-page/?cat=$cat'>" . $cat .   "</a>";
```

With this line

```
 print "<a href='" . get_site_url() . "/band-search-page/?cat=$cat'>" . array_values(array_filter($cat) .   "</a>";
```

Just add array_filter($cat) to remove empty array elements.

Comment: @HollerTrain try `array_values(array_filter($cat));`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understand you correctly, but I'm also working on a site where I only want to show the category name that has posts stored in it. I just checked it by using `if(category_count > 0)`.

Well, you might want to set the category and call it using `get_categories()`, loop through it then you can do `category->count` to check for the count.

hope this might help... someone.. :)